# One or more properties contains invalid values in Microsoft graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to create users on the Azure Active Directory B2C i followed each steps for that in the given link [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet)

URL :- https://graph.windows.net/testinggmail.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.6

Type :- POST

Header :-

```
 Authorization:Bearer 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.YQf6dWra1jua8XMHdqqqd5vrpVUxil_6YMM00drLl9LmOchUY7AtPOXF6T_p7Bmf2BwOWL02bsm7VJCM5cx_TD0cMzbOr4uybmyJJvDqfi1whvgOWbDnY_J9ArJWQMuk7jPIBPS_WT8UYsmM_ivRmcQcRxZtcYCrAaWWOJFeWFVucJFz9G-ld0qi4TU10-Qk9_owREDoitlwYEZwEzSUU-HauDCkjNVzDNhefXrjlJHMzXcsJMnVyX7txkZpiqcsM8H-2EKbFmavT4fN05zUh1Hy6hSLnKv24uDyB3hf2qEZvOaygDUPFRcbFSWH39yp698FGh9Ayr8vHr9wLRHHdA
Content-Type:application/json
```

Request Body :-

```
 { 

    "accountEnabled": true,
    "signInNames": [                            
        {
            "type": "emailAddress",             
            "value": "joeconsumer@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "creationType": "LocalAccount",           
    "displayName": "Joe Consumer",              
    "mailNickname": "joec",                     
    "passwordProfile": {
        "password": "P@ssword!",
        "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false 
    },
    "passwordPolicies": "DisablePasswordExpiration"
}
```

Response :-

```
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en",
            "value": "One or more properties contains invalid values."
        },
        "date": "2018-03-12T07:24:13",
        "requestId": "fef2037f-8c6f-4190-8c5a-727dcccde5eb",
        "values": null
    }
}'
```

Some API'S are working fine like **GetUsers**  and ***TokenAcuire*** but not create user i have googled it also got many solution but didn't worked for me  link is here what else 
i have tried [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35455290/graph-api-request-returning-one-or-more-properties-contains-invalid-values) if i follow that steps for creating separate Direcotry then i get Error Insufficient Privilege to Complete Operation.

Comment: I test in my Lab and suceeded. Did you make sure that `testinggmail.onmicrosoft.com` is a B2C tenant ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This type of user creation with the Azure AD Graph API is for Azure AD B2C:

> Beginning with version 1.6, Graph API supports creating local and
>   social account users for Azure Active Directory B2C tenants.

If you try to use this Azure AD Graph API request for a normal Azure AD tenant, it will get the same error massage as yours.

**So, ensure the tenant you're trying to query is a B2C tenant：**

Try to use the global admin of the B2C tenant (e.g. username@b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com) to obtain a token. Then use the token in the head to use the API :

**Request:**

```
 POST https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users?api-version=1.6
```

**Body Content-Type: application/json:**

```
{ 

    "accountEnabled": true,
    "signInNames": [                            
        {
            "type": "emailAddress",             
            "value": "joeconsumer@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "creationType": "LocalAccount",           
    "displayName": "Joe Consumer",              
    "mailNickname": "joec",                     
    "passwordProfile": {
        "password": "P@ssword!",
        "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false 
    },
    "passwordPolicies": "DisablePasswordExpiration"
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i didn't get it i am obtaining Access token like this,   AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireToken("https://graph.windows.net", credential);

Comment: It doesn't matter, just use the token. But you need to ensure the token is used for the B2C tenant.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue which I fixed by setting the **Content-Type** to **application/json**.

There is also a question on SO with the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35455290/graph-api-request-returning-one-or-more-properties-contains-invalid-values). Basically his error was that he used a Azure Active Directory classic (B2B).

Comment: Yep, if you use Postman, you can set the body to `raw JSON(application/json)`.