# how to use graph api / sdk with AD B2C

Tags: asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to simply create a user using Graph API sdk against my AD B2C tenant but I keep running into issues. I am following the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

The first error I received was that “the domain portion of the userPrincipalName property is invalid. You must use one of the verified domain names in your organization”. After looking around, I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#CreateLocalAccountUser) document that states that the CreationType property must be set to "LocalAccount". When I tried that, I got the error that “one or more properties contains invalid values.”

The error doesn't give any details as to which property is invalid! Can someone at Microsoft please point me to an appropriate document of how to get this working? [It seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49230502/one-or-more-properties-contains-invalid-values-in-microsoft-graph-api) that there might be some confusion in the documentation where the API is possibly targeting AD as opposed to AD B2C. But I do not have an AD tenant, just an AD B2C tenant, and that's what I am targeting. Again, I am using the latest version of the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the issue. For AD B2C, I am supposed to attach an ObjectIdentity to the User object I am passing to be created.

Below is the code:

```
    var identity = new ObjectIdentity
    {
        Issuer = Globals.Tenant,
        IssuerAssignedId = email,
        SignInType = "emailAddress"
    };
    var graphClient = GetGraphServiceClient();
    var user = new User
    {
        DisplayName = fullName,
        PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
        {
            Password = password,
            ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = forceChangePasswordSignIn
        },
        PasswordPolicies = "DisablePasswordExpiration",
        AccountEnabled = enabled,
        CreationType = "LocalAccount",
        Identities = new ObjectIdentity[] { identity }
    };
    var userInfo = await graphClient.Users.Request().AddAsync(user);
    return userInfo;
```

Comment: For reference, here is the doc pertaining to creating a B2C Local Account via Graph SDK: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-2-create-a-user-with-social-and-local-account-identities. Here you can find the sitemap for all AAD B2C Graph API operations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-operations